# IIS 7.5 only shows directory list or 403 instead of ASP.NET Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I successfully used *web deploy* to a IIS 7.5 server in the local network. However when I want to browse the side I only get a **403.14** Error. I can solve this problem by enabling directory browsing but then I only see the directory list instead of the actual application. (basically I see all folders and files from the web deploy)

When I start the application in Visual studio I get the website (login) which is: `localhost:14421/Account/Login`

I also cannot see any .aspx or .html file on the IIS after I did a web deploy. What setting did I miss?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Adding this to the Web.config fixed the issue:

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/> 
</system.webServer>
```

Another way to fix this is installing the hotfix [Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5272)

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem and can not fix it.
And my Web.config seems to be a little different. Is there any way you can help me adding more information?
Or maybe the same update you have mentioned, but my OS is "Windows Server Standard 2007 Service Pack 2"

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I solved it re-targeting the ".Net CLR Version" in the "Edit Application Pool" view which's located in Application Tools Menu (IIS Manager). As soon as I retargeted to the current .Net version I was using for my web project, the website started to work. Below you can see a figure where it's shown what I'm explaining about.

[Configuration of .Net version on Application pools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PlD4N.png)

Answer (score 2):

The following default  element is configured in the root ApplicationHost.config file in IIS 7 when the Directory Browsing role service is installed.

```
<directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
```

Step - 1

The following example enables or disables directory browsing. You can set it in your project's `Web.config` file.

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Step -2

Open IIS Manager -> Directory Browsing -> Right-click on it and click on 'Open Feature' -> On the right side -> Action -> click on Disabled

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have given the full access to IIS_IUSRS to that source folder.

Comment: Yes I did that. But I can only browse all the files but the application is not shown

Comment: How can I check these permissions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have to set up your current application like the below picture, follow a step-by-step guide to setting up:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

MVC appilcation does not installed on your server...

Run this command for install mvc application

`install-windowsfeature web-asp-net45`

or install ASP.Net 4  in role server
[Detail](https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=Windows_Server_2019&p=iis&f=7)